# Trouble interpreting に思う in その武具に思うことはいっぱいあるみたい

Tags: grammar, particle-に, parsing

> 類は友を呼ぶじゃないけどね、やっぱり実際使って直接肌で感じる冒険者の方が、**その武具に思うことはいっぱいあるみたい。**

I'm having trouble interpreting this part of the sentence. What does に思う do here? Does その武具に思うこと mean something like: "Thoughts about the armor"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. This `〜に思うこと` is equivalent to `〜に対して思うこと`.

> 実際使って直接肌で感じる冒険者の方が、その武具に思うことはいっぱいあるみたい。
>   *It seems that adventurers who actually use and experience it firsthand have more thoughts about that armor.*

I can't grasp the full context from this excerpt, but 思うことがある often implies critical, nuanced, or complicated thoughts/feelings.

Similar uses:

- 上司**に思うこと**はたくさんあるんだけど、なかなか言えない。
- 私**に思うこと**があったら、なんでも言ってください。
- 戦争**に思うこと**はいろいろある。