# Uses of に思う in this statement

Tags: grammar

> 俺が疑問に思った一名の欠員について、皆も何かしら不審に思う点があるらしい。

For 疑問に思った does ["〜に思うこと is equivalent to 〜に対して思うこと."](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29619/trouble-interpreting-%e3%81%ab%e6%80%9d%e3%81%86-in-%e3%81%9d%e3%81%ae%e6%ad%a6%e5%85%b7%e3%81%ab%e6%80%9d%e3%81%86%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e3%81%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%b1%e3%81%84%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e3%81%bf%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84) apply? Or is it 疑問と思った?

For 不審に思う, is it mandatory to read it as the adverbial of 不審, or do you interpret it the same as 疑問に思った?

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57223/9831

Comment: In case I guessed right, the true source of the confusion might be, perhaps, that you don't know 疑問 means "questionable" as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two structures are very similar in meaning, however:

With (〜が)〜だと思う you're stating that you think/feel (something) **is** a certain way.

With (〜を)〜に思う you're stating **how** you think/feel (about something).

So 疑問だと思う means "I think/feel (something) is a question".

But 疑問に思う means "I feel dubiously about (something)".

Likewise:

不審だと思う means "I think/feel (something) is suspicious".

But 不審に思う means "I feel suspiciously about (something)".

Comment: so both are adverbial, even though 疑問 isn't listed as an adverb?

Comment: Yes, that is how it is functioning. Also, my dictionary lists it as 〈名ノナ〉 , meaning it's a noun that can also act as adverbial, which makes sense because we can/do say 疑問なこと as well.

Comment: Who is downvoting @sbkgs4686’s answers? They seem quite high quality to me...

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I'm not the downvoter, but 奇妙に思う cannot be translated as  "I strangely feel" or "I feel in a strange manner", right? 疑問だと思う and 疑問に思う sound almost the same to me, except that the latter sounds a little milder.

Comment: I see the problem now, though I think it’s still an interesting parallel; the reason 〜に〜を思う is softer is because it focuses more on the subject’s experience as opposed to the truth claim, like how the adverbial English sentence works. The problem is that in Japanese it is always making the copular truth claim, while some of the English sentences aren’t.

Comment: (In other words 〜が〜だと思う is definitely stating an opinion, while 〜を〜に思う is stating how you felt/thought about something... and I find I’ve just written the same sentence as sbkgs. Hmm :)

Comment: Oh my god, thank you @naruto, I hadn't considered that my answer could be taken that way! I'm in 100% agreement with you. The 奇妙 in 奇妙に思う is definitely not referring to __how__ you're doing the action of thinking/feeling, but how you're thinking/feeling __about__ the object of 思う. My bolding of "how" in my original answer was probably not the best choice.. You should resubmit the answer you deleted, I found your connection with "as" in English really interesting.

Answer (score 7):

XXを疑問/不審に思う means "feel dubious about XX" "feel suspicious about XX", i.e. "feel that XX is questionable" "feel that XX is suspicious".

> 一名の欠員を疑問に思う I feel dubious about one vacancy
>   (≂ ～～をおかしいと思う/疑わしいと思う)
>   その点を不審に思う They feel suspicious about that point
>   (≂ ～～を変だと思う/怪しいと思う)

Similar examples:

> ～～を残念に思う feel sad about ~~ / feel that ~~ is unfortunate
>   ～～を変に思う feel ~~ is strange

疑問に, 不審に, 残念に etc. here are adverbial forms, but they're not describing how the action 思う is performed, but describing what you feel/think the object (the thing marked with を) is.

For more, please refer to: [Confusion with に、を、と particles used with verbs like 感じる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57223/9831)

---

So to answer your questions:

> For 疑問に思った does "〜に思うこと is equivalent to 〜に対して思うこと." apply? Or is it 疑問と思った?

The に in that thread has a different usage/meaning. 疑問と思った is close, but 疑問だと思った might sound a bit more natural.

> For 不審に思う, is it mandatory to read it as the adverbial of 不審, or do you interpret it the same as 疑問に思った?

The latter.