# What does this sentence mean? 『真昼に思ったような事を周にも思ったらしい真昼が素っ気なく返す』

Tags: meaning, translation

> 「とりあえず、一旦出ますから私が帰ってくるまでに着替えておいてください。いいですね」
>
> 「……帰ってくるのかよ」
>
> [放って寝込まれても寝覚めが悪いので」
>
> 前ずぶ濡れの真昼に思ったような**事を周にも思ったらしい真昼が素っ気なく返す**ので、周もそれ以上は文句も言えなかった。([source](https://ncode.syosetu.com/n8440fe/3/))

So the MC (周) helped a girl (真昼?) and give her his umbrella after failing to convince her to not sit in the park while it was raining. The next day she waited in front of his house to return it, only to find him sick with fever. So she helped him inside and this exchange happened. What does 真昼に思ったような事を周にも思ったらしい真昼が素っ気なく返す mean here? I am very confused by the 思った parts.

Comment: Sorry to piggyback this question... what is the difference between が思う and に思う?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72511/uses-of-%E3%81%AB%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86-in-this-statement this could help

Comment: this is different

Answer (score 3):

に is simply *to(wards)* here and にも is *also to*.

> 真昼に思ったような事を what (MC) felt towards Mahiru
>
> 周にも思ったらしい seemingly felt towards Amane

is a relative clause (with an embedded clause) modifying 真昼.

So

> 真昼<sub>1</sub>に<sub>3</sub>思ったような事を周に<sub>4</sub>も思ったらしい真昼<sub>2</sub>が素っ気なく返す

translates

> Mahiru<sub>2</sub>, who seemed to feel (also) for<sub>4</sub> Amane something like what Amane felt for<sub>3</sub> Mahiru<sub>1</sub>, made a simple reply

I marked subscripted numbers to indicate which 真昼 etc. is rendered.