# Understanding『放って寝込まれても目覚めが悪い』

Tags: meaning

This is a follow up [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97927/41067), I am bit uncertain about the meaning of

> 放って寝込まれても目覚めが悪い

I understand 寝込まれて as suffering passive version of 寝込む. The 目覚めが悪い part is ambiguous. I have two ways to interpret the sentence:

1. I will feel bad if I leave you to fall asleep.
2. It will be difficult to wake you up if I leave you to fall asleep.

Which one will make sense?

Comment: It should be [寝覚めが悪い](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/寝覚めが悪い/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be an issue, but [寝込む](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%AF%9D%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80/#je-58305) here should mean 'be sick in bed' (or 'catch a cold' in the particular case).

放って is 'by leaving (you) **in that state** (rather than *to be sick in bed*)'. So, it is roughly 1 in question but more precisely,

- I will wake up in a bad state if I leave you and you end up being sick in bed.

Comment: In addition, 寝覚めが悪い is the proverb means ”I don't feel well (like the mood of waking up) because I did something wrong”.